# Have to delete "/var/lib/bluetooth" folder in order to get all service characteristics available

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In order to keep the pairing information, we carry over the "/var/lib/bluetooth" folder from an older build to the new build in the Linux system when doing firmware upgrade. This way, our end user doesn't have to choose "Forget This Device" each time after the firmware upgrade. Otherwise, our end user has to "Forget This Device" and re-pair because the pairing info can't be found in the Linux device. We also set the GATT cache as "no" in "/etc/bluetooth/main.conf". Then the mobile app won't crash when there is any "service changed" such as adding notification to some existing characteristics.

We organize our characteristics under the services. There are 10 services on the Linux device. Each service has 5 to 10 characteristics. However, we found a new problem recently. The problem is: the first 8 services are fine. But the last one or two services only have the service UUID listed in nRF or our mobile app. There are no characteristics showing up under these one or two services. This caused our mobile app can't read the characteristics data under these problematic services. I checked the nRF. It's the same thing. nRF only shows the last one or two services with the service UUIDs. There are no characteristics listed under those 2 services.

In order to fix this issue, we have to do these(let's call it "The Steps"):

- Remove the "/var/lib/bluetooth" folder from the Linux system
- Restart our BlueZ based service in Python in the Linux system
- Choose "Forget This Device" on the iPhone. After this operation, the "/var/lib/bluetooth" is generated in the Linux device.
- Connect to the device from our mobile app or from nRF. We can see all of the 10 services in the list. Each characteristic under the service can be seen.
- We are able to read the data by using our mobile app or by using nRF

I compared the files in the "/var/lib/bluetooth" folder. As we disabled the GATT cache, there is no "cache" folder. There are only 2 files in the folder. Here is the folder structure:

```
/var/lib/bluetooth:
    |    
    +----00:11:22:33:44:55/
        |
        +----6C:92:11:87:11:25/
            |
            +----attributes
            +----info
```

I kept one copy of the files after the firmware upgrade. I also kept a copy of the files after the folder was re-generated. I compared the file "attributes" and "info". For the attributes, they are the same. For the "info" file, there are only 3 differences:

```
[General]
Name=PhoneX
. . .

[SlaveLongTermKey]
Key=252256E19E26F3ED9FD0B99B7B5B0193
. . .

[LinkKey]
Key=1B593296571E2C48CF6952E60395E304
. . .
```

I don't think these differences could cause the issue. But the fact is, if I delete the "/var/lib/bluetooth" folder and go thru "The Steps" above, the problem will be gone. All of the services will have their characteristics showing up in nRF. The data can be read from the characteristics. This means the folder "/var/lib/bluetooth" is related to the issue. But I don't know why.

Here is also another thing. I subscribed to the "PropertiesChanged" signal. In the callback function "properties_changed", I print out the "changed". Here is the code to subscribe the "PropertiesChanged":

```
        bus.add_signal_receiver(
            properties_changed,
            dbus_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
            signal_name="PropertiesChanged",
            arg0="org.bluez.Device1",
            path_keyword="path",
        )
```

If the folder "/var/lib/bluetooth" is removed and go thru "The Steps", I saw the log like this:

```
dbus.Dictionary({dbus.String('UUIDs'): dbus.Array([dbus.String('00000000-deca-fade-deca-deafdecacafe'), 
dbus.String('00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String('0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), 
dbus.String('0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String('0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), 
dbus.String('00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String('0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), 
dbus.String('0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String('00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), 
dbus.String('00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String('00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), 
dbus.String('00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String('00001805-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), 
dbus.String('0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), dbus.String('0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'), 
dbus.String('02030302-1d19-415f-86f2-22a2106a0a77'), dbus.String('7905f431-b5ce-4e99-a40f-4b1e122d00d0'), 
dbus.String('89d3502b-0f36-433a-8ef4-c502ad55f8dc'), dbus.String('9fa480e0-4967-4542-9390-d343dc5d04ae'), 
dbus.String('d0611e78-bbb4-4591-a5f8-487910ae4366')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'), variant_level=1),
dbus.String('ServicesResolved'): dbus.Boolean(True, variant_level=1)}, signature=dbus.Signature('sv'))
```

If I check the log after the firmware is upgraded without deleting the "/var/lib/bluetooth" folder, the log looks like this:

```
dbus.Dictionary({dbus.String('ServicesResolved'): dbus.Boolean(True, variant_level=1)}, 
signature=dbus.Signature('sv'))
```

As we can see, they are different. Is it something to do with D-Bus?

We understand that if we don't carry over the "/var/lib/bluetooth" folder, then there is no this issue. But our end user will have to choose "Forget This Device" each time after the firmware is upgraded. Otherwise, the end user can't connect to the Linux device because the pairing info can't be found. Is there a way to fix this issue? Namely, is there a way to keep the pairing info and also avoid this issue for firmware upgrade?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added the two problematic services with a DFU or have they existed (and worked) before?

Comment: It is random. For example, today I tested it again. There are 5 services which only have the service itself showing up in nRF. About 30 characteristics under those 5 services can't be seen. I'm not sure DFU and how it works. But these services and characteristics works fine for normal operation in the firmware. After firmware upgrade, they have issues. Our GATT server is based on https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-gatt-server.

Comment: On Android devices using nRF Connect you can connect to a device and select "Refresh services" in the menu (3 dots in upper right corner). Could you try that to rule out some weird caching issue on your mobile devices? Which mobile devices are showing these problems?

Comment: Just found this thread: https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/16233/nrf-connect-fails-when-using-many-characteristics This might be an issue related to android

Comment: Great info. The device I'm using is iPhone 6S. Our QA engineers use Andriod phone. They found the same issue. I didn't know the number of characteristics could cause problem. For us, we have 8 services with 85 characteristics. If we have too many characteristics, then how come things work fine by removing the "/var/lib/bluetooth" folder and re-do the pairing? It's weird the files in "/var/lib/bluetooth" folder are either identical or very similar. For "attributes" file, they are identical. For "info" file, only SlaveLongTermKey and LinkKey are different as re-pairing.

Comment: It might be something else if you are seeing the same issue on iOS and Android. I'm out of ideas unfortunately. You could still try "refresh services" on the Android phone. If this helps there might be some hope implementing the "Service Changed characteristic". But you said you don't change services during a DFU...

Comment: There are about 90 characteristics. I suspect maybe we have "too many" characteristics. I'll try to combine some characteristics and make it about 30 characteristics in total. Well, we wanted to enable the "Service Changed Indication"(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65835507/how-to-enable-the-service-changed-inidcation0x2a05-on-the-gatt-server). But we don't know how to do it. So we disabled the cache in the Server side.